# sendmail failed to send email to gmail

Tags: sendmail

```
[root@jiaoyou ~]# sendmail -t< mail.txt 
[root@jiaoyou ~]# cat mail.txt 
From: abc@gmail.com
To: abc@gmail.com
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
Subject: Test HTML e-mail.

This is a MIME-encapsulated message
```

Anything wrong here?

Comment: How about the complete lack of details?  Is your sendmail set up correctly? Are you relaying through your ISP, or sending directly to gmail? How do you know it failed? Logs?

Comment: I didn't receive the email from my gmail account.

Answer (score 1):

Gmail won't forward mail. You can only send mail via gmail as an authenticated user.

Answer (score 0):

Gmail will generally pop up a message in the from account asking you if you want to allow someone else to send mail from you. Once this is enabled it should go through.

Also, check your mailq.

Comment: Is there anything wrong with my usage of sendmail here?

Comment: Doesn't look that way. Its going to require logs from the server so, as Bill said, sendmail could be setup to not forward mail and it could be just sitting in your mailq.
Run mailq, then check /var/log/mail.info